# Change appearance based on category but post is in two main categories

Tags: categories, menus, headers

I want to change header and menu based on what category a post is listed in.

I could duplicate the post and assigned each of the two categories separately but this sounds messy and bleh.

The post/s in this example belong in both "pirtek" and "btcc".

http://www.talkativebroadcasting.co.uk/

but the posts with pirtek need to be styled with custom header etc. (and eventually custom menu...which makes me think perhaps I should just duplicate for easy implementation of a seperate menu?)

What do you think? As it stands my standard header is prioritised every time

```
    <php
if ( has_category('pirtek') ) {
  $header = 'http://www.talkativebroadcasting.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/cropped-pirtekheader.png'
} else {
  $header = 'http://talkativebroadcasting.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cropped-talkativeheader2.png'
}
?>
```

Comment: Post your code, please, but it should be easy enough to give `pirtek` priority.

Comment: Maybe your problem is probably the use of relative urls. Rigth way to retrieve the full url of your uploads folder is to use [`wp_upload_dir`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) function. After that, why are you calling `get_header_image()` if then you use different images urls?

Comment: How about my updated code? That is still not showing any header. Am I getting the wrong syntax?

Comment: hmmm will category templates be a better option? Will that give me the option of displaying a different menu entirely if that category is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to use [`has_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) function.

E.g. in your header you can use

```
if ( has_category('pirtek') ) {
  $header = '/path/to/pirtek/header'
} else {
  $header = '/path/to/standard/header'
}
```

If the post has the 'kirtek' category, then the condition inside `if` is `true`, no matter what other categories the post belongs to.

This kind of `if` statement can be used everywhere you need, however, the snippet above works well in singular templates and inside the loop. If you want to use that conditional outside the loop, you need to pass the post object as second argument of `has_category`.

```
$postid = 10;

if ( has_category( get_post($postid) ) ) {
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. having a bit of beginner woes but i understand what it should be doing. my guess is its slightly wrong as I am not getting a header at the moment! Please see revised initial question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if ( has_category('pirtek') ) {
$header_image = "http://www.talkativebroadcasting.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/cropped-pirtekheader.png";
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( "http://www.pirtek.co.uk/" ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; }

else {
$header_image = "http://talkativebroadcasting.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cropped-talkativeheader2.png";
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; }

?>
```

For reference this code in header.php does exactly what I need. Many thanks!